# Using vars as an argument in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use vars in my ansible playbook. `ENV` will be passed as an input from the command line.

```
---
- hosts: development
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: root
  vars:
        env: "{{ ENV|default('DEV') }}"
  roles:
        # Copy conf files
        - { role: copy, src: ./conf/ems/7000/"{{ env }}"/*.conf , dest: /apps/tibco/config/ems/7000/data/ }
        - { role: copy, src: ./conf/ems/7000/"{{ env }}"/*.conf , dest: /apps/tibco/config/ems/7200/data/ }
        - { role: copy, src: ./conf/ems/7000/"{{ env }}"/*.conf , dest: /apps/tibco/config/ems/7004/data/ }
```

I run this playbook by the command

```
ansible-playbook -e 'ENV=DEV' --ask-sudo-pass install-ems-plybook.yml
```

I get

```
        # Copy conf files
        - { role: copy, src: ./conf/ems/7000/" {{env}} "/*.conf , dest: /apps/tibco/config/ems/7000/data/ }
                                               ^
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

Please be explicit in answer as I am still a toddler in Ansible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Main problem**:

You shouldn't include quotes in the middle of the string (`./conf/ems/7000/"{{ env }}"/*.conf`) - that's what you got an error message about - it should be `"./conf/ems/7000/{{ env }}/*.conf"`

**Other problems**:

You seem to really want to define tasks not roles; I assume this from naming of the parameters.

You didm't specify (in words) what you want to achieve, I assume you wanted to copy files from a local directory to a directory on the target node.

One major problem is that you cannot use wildcards in `copy` module; to copy multiple files you should use `with_fileglob`, see [Looping over Fileglobs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#id4)

Another minor problem is that `sudo` and `sudo_user` are deprecated and replaced with `become` and `become_user`, they are still aliases producing warning messages, but there is no guarantee disappear one day.

A working example playbook can look like this:

```
---
- hosts: development
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  vars:
    env: "{{ ENV|default('DEV') }}"
  tasks:
    - copy:
        src: "{{ item }}"
        dest: /apps/tibco/config/ems/7000/data/
      with_fileglob:
        - "./conf/ems/7000/{{ env }}/*.conf"
```

Finally, in your example, you copy the same set of files from the directory containing `7000` to directories containing `7000`, `7200`, and `7004`. I'm not sure if this is what you intended, but I leave that to your customisation. You can add tasks as per the example above.

Comment: does become_user is supported in 1.9 ?

Comment: Yes, according to [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#for-those-from-pre-1-9-sudo-and-su-still-work) `become`-parameters were introduced in 1.9.